# Как менять изображение на кнопке открытия-закрытия меню?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на чистом JavaScript сделать замену изображения на кнопке открытия-закрытия меню.

Есть кнопка для открытия-закрытия меню.
По умолчанию на ней есть исходное фоновое изображение.
Необходимо, чтобы при открытии меню, изображение на кнопке подменялось на изображение крестика, а при закрытии, возвращалось исходное изображение.

Написал JS для тогла класса для скрытия и открытия меню, а также для смены исходного изображения на крестик, а как при закрытии меню вернуть исходное изображение на кнопку не знаю.

```
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu-bar');
const toggleMenuBtn = document.querySelector('.js-toggle-menu');

const changeBgImage = () => {
  toggleMenuBtn.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/icon-close.svg)';
};

const handleToggleMenuBtnClick = e => {
  menu.classList.toggle('show');
  changeBgImage();
};

toggleMenuBtn.addEventListener('click', handleToggleMenuBtnClick);
```

Comment: Сделайте добавление класса кнопке, в классе укажите фоновое изображение, а все остальное как у вас для `.menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const toggleMenuBtn = document.querySelector('.js-toggle-menu');

const handleToggleMenuBtnClick = e => toggleMenuBtn.classList.toggle('js-toggle-menu_show');

toggleMenuBtn.addEventListener('click', handleToggleMenuBtnClick);
```

```css
.js-toggle-menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/100/000000/phone.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

.js-toggle-menu_show {
  background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/ios/100/000000/phone.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="js-toggle-menu"></div>
```